# Autostart script depending on internet connection

Tags: shell, fedora

I want to run script automatically, but it (script) depends on my internet connection. So when I put it in /etc/init.d catalog, it crashes before I make internet connection. I found perfect answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection

...BUT this answer is suitable for Ubuntu - on Fedora I don't even have /etc/network catalog. Any similar is /etc/networks, but script put there didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora have the network scripts in

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
```

So you can follow similar procedure to achieve the same.

Comment: Same as before, unfortunetally.